# .Net 6 Application with EntityFramework 6.0 in Linux Container

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-6.0, linux-containers

I have an application which uses Entity Framework 6.0 for data access. I'm converting my application to .Net 6 and later it will be deployed into Linux container.

As per Microsoft website, Entity Framework 6.0 is supported in .Net core.

```
EF6
Entity Framework 6 (EF6) is an object-relational mapper designed for .NET Framework but with support for .NET Core. EF6 is a stable, supported product, but is no longer being actively developed.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/

But my question is, If I convert my application to .Net 6 and still using Entity Framework 6.0, will it be supported in Linux container. As per Microsoft, Linux Container supports .Net 6 applications but still I am going to use Entity Framework 6 within my .Net 6 application.

Can someone shed some light on this?

I did some research on Google but I did not find any official refernce link stating .Net 6 with Entity Framework 6.0 supported in Linux Container or not.

Comment: Create a .Net core application with docker support, add EF 6 and try it. Shouldn't take longer then 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's a .net core project, no matter what package you are using. After build then deploy to docker, it will work.
But I still recommand you to use efcore in asp.net core project, as the samples and relevant support are up to date.
Using efcore is pretty simple.https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core.aspx